# Optional parameter GET - query

Tags: php, yii

**main.php**

```
'admin/<alias>/<munu>' => 'mycontroller/pd'
```

Mycontroller

```
public function actionPd($alias, $munu)
{
    var_dump($alias);
    var_dump($munu);               
}
```

Parameter $munu  can not be Set in URI-query.
How to fix the line  `'admin/<alias>/<munu>'` when prompted to **localhost/admin/profile** there was no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

> ```
> 'admin/<alias>/<munu>' => 'mycontroller/pd'
> 'admin/<alias>' => 'mycontroller/pd'
> ```

and change to (set default val for $munu):

> ```
> public function actionPd($alias, $munu = null)
> {
>     var_dump($alias);
>     var_dump($munu);
> }
> ```

Comment: The URL pattern "admin/<alias>/<munu:{0,1}>" for route  is not a valid regular expression.